# how to use require.js define a template like vue component and connect the data

Tags: express, vue.js, requirejs

In projects that use express + require.js and vue cdn, I try to use require.js to define a template similar to vue components

In index.js, I have a data list, I want to use v-for in the index.html display list item, but I cannot connect the data list in html

This is my code, is there any mistake?

index.js

```js
define([
    'text!js/components/search/index.html',
    'jquery',
], function (template) {
    var $ = require('jquery');
    var Vue = require('vue');
    var ajax = require('js/ajax');
    return {
        name: 'search',
        template: require('text!js/components/search/index.html'),
        props: {

        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                // data list
                Options: [],
            };
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.loadOptions();
        },
        methods: {
            //data list
            loadOptions() {
                ajax.get('/options/options').then(function (data) {
                    this.Options = data.Options;
                    console.log('this.Options Successful get data')
                });
            },
        },
    };
});
```

index.html

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6 ">
    <a class="dropdown-item"
        href="#"
        v-for="opt in Options"
        :key="opt.value">
        <p :title="opt.label">
            {{ opt.label }}
        </p>
    </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because of `this`?

I assume that `console.log('this.Options Successful get data')` works as expected. Try to change your `loadOptions` method as follows:

```js
loadOptions() {
                ajax.get('/options/options').then(data => {
                    this.Options = data.Options;
                    console.log('this.Options Successful get data')
                });
            },
```

Arrow function should help to point `this` to your Vue component instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After the change, I got the list item data

Answer (score 0):

From the code, your template file lives at `components/search/index.html`, is the file being referenced properly?

Better still, Please put your code in a sandbox/jsfiddle and share the link. So, it would be easy for anyone to look at it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will improve